# Can lvm put metadata lv to specific device?

Tags: linux, lvm

As title, I want to locate metadata lv onto a SSD to improve performance.

We know metadata lv is like `vg1/mypool_tmeta` if created a `vg1` and thinpool `mypool`.

EX: I want to put `mypool_tmeta` on another **fast** disk/device like `vg2/lv2` which `vg2` is based on SSD disk and vg1 is HDD disk.

Is there any way to change/specify metadata lv to other disk/device ?